# Android Remote Chrome Debug in Adobe Air StageWebView

Tags: android, actionscript-3, google-chrome, air, remote-debugging

I am able to [usb remote debug](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging) a `StageWebView` in Adobe Air application on a rooted Android Galaxy Note 2 running 4.4.x. This is from a Macbook running Mavericks.

It maybe a driver issue, but the remote debug does not work on windows the same way.

Trying a Galaxy Note 3 with 4.4.1 I cannot get the web view to see the `StageWebView` instance to appear on the `chrome://inspect/#devices` with a  and usb debugging enabled in the same way as the Galaxy Note 2. This is with the same Macbook running Mavericks.

The official documentation says Android 4.4+ support for `Android apps: Android 4.4+ and a WebView`.

Can anyone share some insight into their experience with device support for the remote debugging for `StageWebView`? The Adobe documentation does not seem to help on this either.

Comment: I'm interested if this works for ios webview...

Comment: It also works in windows with chrome v41.0.0.2272 and Samsung Galaxy S3 with Android v4.4.4

Comment: @b3wii Yes Safari remote debug has worked for me.

Comment: RLY? Did you set _enableRemoteInspector in your Air code somewhere? Could you please describe...

Comment: @b3wii no do you even have access to that in Air? Only on a mac though, I just followed the safari remote debugging docs, just enable the web inspector on the device general->safari->advanced and in the desktop safari enable developer tools and the device ends up in the develop menu bar entry when the stagewebview instance is running.

Comment: The website loaded in stagewebview doesnt show up in Safari->developer. I tried everything listed on here http://goo.gl/YidbgF... It works when remote debugging websites of mobile safari but not stagewebview content. Did your ios device really show up in Safari? And were you able to debug the content loaded in Stagewebview via Web Inspector?

Comment: It works perfectly to me, debugging stagewebview instances in Safari desktop. Probably there are a couple of things you have to keep in mind: 1 - use nativebrowser in StageWebView, 2 - export a debugger version of the app.

Answer (score 0):

This works on iOS connected to a Mac running Safari, as long as native browser is used and app is in debug mode. On Chrome though, with a Xiaomi Note 7 on both windows and Mac, no luck, no browser instance appears in chrome.